# Displaying League of Legends Logo in my Mobile App

Tags: copyright

I am building a mobile app to do things with friends. Among the list of activities, I want to add a game "League of Legends". If I make a custom logo to represent the game (looks similar to the official logo but more minimalistic) and use in my app, am I infringing the copyright?

Answer (score 0):

If the logo is similar enough to be confused with the official logo, you might have a problem with trademark infringement, rather than copyright. However, if you are not selling your app, nor using it to sell or advertise anything, trsademark protection is far less likely to apply.